# Passing transactional information to new thread(CompletableFuture)

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, transactions

Since my main thread is running in a `@Transactional` context, any error will cause all MySQL queries to be rolled back. However, within my code, I need to run `CompletableFuture.runAsync()` to execute a few query updates in parallel. This creates a new thread with a new transaction, which means that a rollback if any errors occur is not possible.

Can anyone guide me on how to achieve the same transactional behavior inside a thread created by `CompletableFuture`?